# Poner linea de regresión a un scatterplot usando ggglags

Tags: r, rstudio

Cuando escribo el siguiente codigo no me sale la linea de regresión. No sé si tendrá algo que ver con el geom_smooth() que quizas no sea compatible con el ggflags. Sin embargo, cuando el summary y pongo los datos de la linea en el geom_abline() si funciona. Alguien que sepa como se pudiese hacer unicamente con geom_smooth() ?

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggflags)

growth <- c(0.022166490, 0.015537275, 0.019121459, 0.031212145, 0.023109544, 0.029800666, -0.007361123, 0.010905005, 0.011461950, 0.034883724, 0.012864103, 0.013195931, 0.012810806, 0.004175298, 0.016506161, 0.011542311, 0.011797878, 0.011126556, 0.008925284, 0.011553333, 0.015719247, 0.013106895, 0.006300646)

countries <- c("bg", "cz", "hu", "pl", "ro", "sk", "ua", "dk", "fi", "ie", "no", "se", "gb", "it", "si", "es", "at", "be", "fr", "de", "lu", "nl", "ch")

gini <- c(0.3070000, 0.2070000, 0.2100000, 0.2520000, 0.2330000, 0.2020000, 0.2970000, 0.2620000, 0.2220000, 0.3550000, 0.2492857, 0.2303333, 0.3140000, 0.3250000, 0.2360000, 0.3440000, 0.2300000, 0.2520000, 0.3596000, 0.2920000, 0.2670000, 0.2760000, 0.3537000)

df <- data.frame(growth, countries, gini)

ggplot(df, aes(x=gini, y=growth, country=countries)) + 
    geom_flag() + 
    scale_country() +
    geom_smooth(method = lm) +
    scale_size(range = c(0, 7))

summary(lm(df$growth ~ df$gini))

ggplot(df, aes(x=gini, y=growth, country=countries)) + 
    geom_flag() + 
    scale_country() +
    geom_abline(intercept = 0.02620, slope = -0.04178, colour = "black", size = 1) +
    scale_size(range = c(0, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Por alguna razón que desconozco, el mapeo global `ggplot(df, aes(x=gini, y=growth, country=countries))`, y en particular la estética `countries`, trae problemas al `geom_smooth()`. La solución que puedes implementar, es mapear `country` a nivel de `geom_country()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=gini, y=growth)) + 
  geom_flag(mapping = aes(country=countries)) + 
  scale_country() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 7))
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]